# DocuSign permanent authentication?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm sure that I'm missing something, but I'm a little stuck. As part of a sign-up process we are building, we need to send a signature request to the person that signs up. For that, we want to use the eSignatures API.

I'm getting stuck on the Authentication process. Not the authentication itself, that works fine, but I'm not sure how this is going to keep working. As I understand, the tokens are going te expire eventually and I will need to get a new authorization code to request new ones. However, getting that code requires an in-browser permission by the DocuSign user. In my mind, that means this API integration is going to break every now and then and a manual permission is needed?

Comment: There should be a `refresh_token` in the respond allowing you to get a new `access token` , they have longer life span so you don't have to require user to login every time. But they also expire eventually requiring you to ask the user to login again. This is a very common security measure for pretty much any API in the world. Expiration allows for damage control in case a token gets stolen

Comment: Thank you @sinanspd, I found the refresh_tokens, but read that they also expire. So far I've only implemented APIs which use an API-key which doesn't expire. I'm curious though, how would that work in a flow like ours? We build a signup process in which we use the API, how would you prevent this flow from breaking if at some point the docusign user has to login again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/), then yes, you will have to [use refresh tokens](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/#using-refresh-tokens) and then even these eventually expire.

If you use [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/), you only need to get [consent once per-user](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/) (or use [administrative consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-external/) for entire account) and then you won't need to have user log again or do anything again to obtain new access token ever.

Comment: Thank you very much Inbar, I thought we had chosen the best authentication option with the Auth Code Grant, but JWT seems to be what we need!

Comment: Any way to automate the initial consent?  Like with the first time you make the call to create the envelope?

Comment: No, but it's a one time thing only, you do it once and it's not need ever again. No need to automate something like this.

Comment: So, I'm trying to set up a process that uses a form to populate an engagement letter template with specific information from the client and additional fields for the client to fill out and then sign. I want to be able to have the form send a link to the client when submitted, so they can fill out the needed information and sign.  With JWT it's my understanding that I authenticate once and that's it, but I don't think it works that way based on how I want it to work.

Comment: Have you considered using PowerForms?

Comment: I looked at it, but not sure it would do what I need.  It does as far as using a template, but some of the information on the template changes.  For example, SOW and cost.  My takeaway was I'd need a new template each time I sent out a different SOW. 

I have a meeting with DocuSign to go over this.  I'll take another look at  PowerForms, run through it and see if it does what I need it to do.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have technical questions.